# Magento Hide shipping method for specific product

Tags: product, magento-1.8, checkout, shipping, shipping-methods

Hide Shipping Information and Shipping Method steps at checkout page for specific products.

Products may be of any type(Simple, Configurable, ...).

There will be a checkbox on the product page in the admin section for hiding shipping steps on the checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not provide this type of function. If you want to do this, then you need to use the third party extension like
[Amasty](https://amasty.com/shipping-per-product.html) etc.

And this is the only solution for product wise shipping method. But if you want to hide Shipping Address then you need customization to skip shipping address.

A lot of tasks is needed for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Shipping Information and Shipping Method is not required for downloadable and virtual product types, why don't you create your products using those product types?

Cheers
S